# CSS Gradient does not appear

Tags: css

whats wrong with this: I want to put a gradient in the background of the web iste.

$(body).css({ 'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom,rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(241,250,254) 100%)' });

im using this library:
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: remove vendor prefix

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can easily see what the error is by checking the console.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

- You forgot to surround body selector with quotes:

  ```
  $('body')
  ```
- You're using **'linear-gradient'** with **-moz-** vendor prefix
  (Mozilla). Vendors add prefixes to experimental or nonstandard CSS
  properties. Modern browsers don't require these prefixes when using gradient and you should use them only to support some older versions.
- First argument is used to describe gradient
  direction: it can be an angle, e.g. *45deg* or words: *'to left'*,
  *'to right'*, *'to top'*, *'to bottom'* or a combination for diagonal gradient, e.g. *'to bottom right'*. Default value is 'to bottom'.

Take a look at the snippet.

```js
$('body').css({
  'background': 'linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,255,255) 0%,rgb(241,250,254) 100%)'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>From white to very light blue.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out to be much easier by simply doing

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, skyblue  0%, blue 100%)
```